# qt: incorrect return value from invokemethod from inherited superclass

Tags: c++, qt, reflection, qt4

I have a Light class inheriting a Transform class inheriting from QObject.  The Transform class has a center() function that returns a Point3 (typedef of QVector3D).  I'm trying to call invokeMethod on a light object, but am getting an incorrect return value.  Am I calling the function incorrectly?

```
QObject* obj = qobject_cast<QObject*>(lObj);

std::cout << lObj->center() << std::endl;

QVector3D retVal;
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(obj, "center",
                                       Qt::DirectConnection,
                                       Q_RETURN_ARG(QVector3D, retVal));

std::cout << retVal << std::endl;
```

and here's what I get out...

```
(0,10,0) // from lObj->center()
(0,0,0) // from invokeMethod(...)
```

Here's some of my code...

```
typedef QVector3D Point3;

class Transformable : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INVOKABLE Point3             center() { return _center; }
    ...
};

class Light : public Transformable, public Entity  // Entity is a non-Qt-related class
{
};

class PointLight : public Light
{
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Incorrect Return Value`? Did you verify which function is *actually* getting called? Put some breakpoints or traces and verify which function gets called, Base class or the Derived class version.

Comment: Why are you casting, and why are you **not** checking the return value of `invokeMethod`?

Comment: I figured checking the return value is useful for checking programmatically if the function fails, but since I'm inspecting the values anyway, I know it's failing anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use qRegisterMetaType to register the Point3 typedef.

```
typedef QVector3D Point3;
qRegisterMetaType<Point3>("Point3");
```

then use this type at the invoke method instead of the QVector3D

```
Point3 retVal;
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(obj, "center",
                                       Qt::DirectConnection,
                                       Q_RETURN_ARG(Point3, retVal));
```

For more details check the [invoke method documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod) and the [qRegisterMetaType documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType).

Comment: I figured typedef wouldn't allow typedefs for whatever reason.  I couldn't use qRegisterMetaType without the error: "specializing member '::qRegisterMetaType<Point3>' requires 'template<>' syntax.  However, switching to just Point3 worked fine.